# PostGIS: Is it interesting to create an index on geom column and an alpha numeric field?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index, indexing

I would like to know if it's interesting to create an index on an other column than the geom one.

In some cases, I would like to do spatial analysis. If not, I would like to analyse only attributes.

So, should I make a second index on an alpha/numeric field?

EDIT: The practical case is few inserts (adn feature by feature) and a lot of selects on spatial or attributes (one main field as an ID (int) ) or both

Comment: Probably the index will speed up your queries. You can use EXPLAIN to see if index is used.

Comment: Yes, as for any table. Having a geometry or a spatial index is irrelevant when considering adding a(nother) index. Field selectivity, usage in a `sort by` etc are the key factors

Comment: This is more a pure SQL than GIS question. Adding indexes improves *some* query performance, but *always* slows INSERT performance. We don't have enough information about your exact use pattern to make anything but an opinion-based answer.

Comment: ok @Vince, i added a practical case.